# get output from nsExec::Exec

Tags: nsis

I am trying to get the standard output from nsExec. for example, this should display a current date in MessageBox:

```
  nsExec::Exec 'date /t'
  Pop $0
  MessageBox MB_OK "$0"
```

Apparently thats not how you do it. It only displays `1`. What is the correct way of getting the output back from `nsExec::Exec`

Comment: Do you actually want to know the time or is that just an example?

Comment: I actually want to know the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

::Exec just hides stdout, you want ::ExecToStack.

The syntax looks like this:

```
nsExec::Exec '"App"' 
Pop $0 ; Exit code / error

nsExec::ExecToStack '"App"' 
Pop $0 ; Exit code / error
Pop $1 ; stdout output
```

You got an error code because `time` is a built-in command in cmd.exe, not an application. You need to invoke cmd.exe to perform that command:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack '"$sysdir\cmd.exe" /C time /t' 
Pop $0 ; Exit code / error, should be 0
Pop $1 ; Time
```

If all you wanted was to know the time you could also do this:.

```
System::Call 'kernel32::GetLocalTime(p@r0)'
System::Call '*$0(&i2, &i2, &i2, &i2, &i2.r4, &i2.r5, &i2.r6, &i2)'
IntFmt $5 "%.2d" $5 ; 0 pad
IntFmt $6 "%.2d" $6 ; 0 pad
MessageBox mb_ok $4:$5:$6
```